# Noob question: Keras shapes are incompatible

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

I'm a student in datascience and I'm trying to work with deep learning. The model I have is as follows:

```
Model: "sequential_32"

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)           (None, 27, 27, 32)        288       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 13, 13, 128)       4224      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 13, 13, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 13, 13, 10)        1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 5,802
Trainable params: 5,802
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now I'm trying to fit some data into it with the following code:

```
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
result = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Which outputs the following:

```
(60000, 28, 28, 1)
(10000, 28, 28, 1)
# some error codes followed by:
ValueError: Shapes (32, 10) and (32, 13, 13, 11) are incompatible
```

I feel like it really is an easy mistake to fix but I just can't see it. Any help and/ or explanation is welcome!

Comment: From the above model, I would guess that you are missing a `Flatten` layer after the `max pooling`. Therefore it seems that your model output is a `(13, 13, 10)`, instead of a single softmax of size `10`. The shape error you get is probably the `y` value shape not matching the models output shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Thymen's response helped me. Thank you. The model now looks like this:

```
Model: "sequential_35"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_29 (Conv2D)           (None, 27, 27, 32)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 5408)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 128)               692352    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 693,802
Trainable params: 693,802
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```